# Adding time stamp to Kubernetes deployment with latest tag

Tags: kubernetes, yaml

I am trying to implement Kubernetes resource deployment. For this I created `deployment.yaml` and `service.yaml` as my Kubernetes reources. And refering the dockerhub registry image with `latest` tag in my `deployment.yaml. When I am doing like this, latest image is not pulling with`latest` tag.

So I added the time stamp in deployment like following:

```
template:
 metadata:
  labels:
    app: test-kube-deployment
    date: date "+%H:%M:%S   %d/%m/%y"
spec:
  imagePullSecrets:
    - name: "regcred"
  containers:
   - name: test-kube-deployment-container
     image: spacestudymilletech010/spacestudykubernetes:latest
     imagePullPolicy: Always
     ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 8085
          protocol: TCP
```

When I added time here , I am getting the error like the following,

```
The Deployment "test-kube-deployment" is invalid: spec.template.labels: Invalid value: "date \"+%H:%M:%S   %d/%m/%y\"": a valid label must be an empty string or consist of alphanumeric characters, '-', '_' or '.', and must start and end with an alphanumeric character
```

Here what modification that I need to do to define my time stamp for uniquely identify my Docker image?

Comment: Don't add it as a label, but rather as an annotation.
```
template:
 metadata:
  labels:
    app: test-kube-deployment
  annotations:
    date: "+%H:%M:%S   %d/%m/%y"
    date: date "+%H:%M:%S   %d/%m/%y"
```

Comment: Better still would be to make it be the tag of the image, for example `.../spacestudykubernetes:20191025.2302`.  If this image doesn't work for whatever reason then it's very straightforward to revert back to a previous image.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't add it as a label, but rather as an annotation.

```
template: 
  metadata: 
    labels: 
      app: test-kube-deployment 
    annotations: 
      date: "+%H:%M:%S %d/%m/%y"
```

PD.- You are getting the error because labels don't accept the +, % and : characters.

Comment: "+%H:%M:%S %d/%m/%y" is not resolved to valid date, annotation is created as it is a string

Answer (score 0):

I've faced same issue and solved it using annotation. As label not accept the special characters.

```
kubectl patch deployment deploy_name --patch '{"spec": {"template": {"metadata": {"annotations": {"last_update": '"\"$(date '+%Y%m%d%H%M%S')\""'}}}}}';
```